# How to add a button :"Get my location" in page views

Tags: views, location, google-maps

i have created a gmap views page, and i want add a button "get my location like this :

[image]

i want give to visitor a button that can get his location in the map,
some one have an idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) for that task. It will provide you with a block that contains a button with the asked functionality. The user location will be determined via several methods:

> Finally IPGV&M provides a set of visitor location retrieval
>   technologies, both IP and HTML5-based, so that you can track where
>   past visits came from and where current visitors are located,
>   superimposing their moving positions as markers on your maps.

Please read carefully about the requirements.